# Deleting kdump files from /boot

Tags: linux, boot

My `/boot` drive is getting full. The two largest files are:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 10697542 Nov  6  2017 initrd-3.0.13-0.27-default-kdump
-rw------- 1 root root  9386577 Feb 10  2011 initrd-2.6.32.12-0.7-default-kdump
```

Can I safely delete these files? I am assuming that these are just diagnostic dumps and not needed, but want to check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's safe to delete these. They're dump files from kernel crashes.

- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdump_%28Linux%29?wprov=sfla1

You may want to take a quick look to see why the kernel crashed. At least get a sense if these are old or more recent crashes.